# How to modify the existing array object by type in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to modify the array object by type in javascript,
I have a object in which fields type if only array change to as shown below(neglect the image which is always the last element) in javascript

```
function modifyObject(ob){
  var result = ob.map(e=>{
    Array.isArray(e.fields) ? e.fields.map(i=>({i:i}) :  
    Object.assign({}, ...ob.map(elm=>(elm.fields)));
  }
  )
}
var r1 = this.modifyObject(obj1);
var r2 = this.modifyObject(obj2);
var obj1=[
  {
    fields: {"cn":"IN"},
    id: 0,
    group: "Active"
  }
]

var obj2 =[
  {
    fields: ["city","name","img.jpg"],
    id: 0,
    group: "Active"
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
//if fields type is array
  {
    fields: {city:"city", name:"name"}  
  }

//if fields type is object 
  {
    fields: {"cn":"IN"}
  }
```

Comment: how about img.jpg? what to you want to display with its key?

Comment: @elpmid thanks for reply, no need to add img.jpg,( image alwys present in last element of fields)

Comment: so, there is no logic...

Comment: Why are you not returning anything (`result`) from `modifyObject` function?

Comment: Why does `this` in `var r1 = this.modifyObject(obj1);` mean?

Comment: Why is `r1` using `obj1` before assigning value to `obj1` (and 2)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your obj1 and obj2 are not objects, they're array containg one object each. modifiedObj would have to receive myObj[0], or you could modify it as I did:

```
function modifyObject(myObj) {
  let modifiedObj = myObj;
  if (Array.isArray(modifiedObj.fields)) {
    let objFields = {};
    modifiedObj.fields.forEach(field => objFields[field] = field);
    modifiedObj.fields = objFields;
  }
  return modifiedObj; 
}

var obj1 = {
  fields: {"cn":"IN"},
  id    : 0,
  group : "Active"
};
var obj2 = {
  fields: ["city","name","img.jpg"],
  id    : 0,
  group : "Active"
};

var r2 = modifyObject(obj2);
console.log(r2);
```

Let me know if it's unclear.
Please give me a +rep if it helps.